# invalid_json when importing to CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb

I'm getting an invalid JSON error when trying to add new JSON data to a couchapp.

I have JSON data that I converted from a CSV, and have been trying to add it with _bulk_docs to a couchapp. I solved the most obvious JSON errors with a JSON validator: http://jsonlint.com/

But one of the files is still giving an error, even thought the validator says the JSON is valid.

```
curl -d @songs_raw2.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST     http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/songs/_bulk_docs
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
```

The file is here:
https://github.com/anatighe/sacred-harp/blob/master/songs_raw2.json

Comment: This is working for me.. are you sure that songs_raw2.json file on your local machine contains the same data that you have posted on github.

Comment: I pushed it directly to Github from my directory. The JSON tests ok, but I get an error when importing to Couch. Were you able to import the data to couch?

Comment: yep. I saved the raw file locally on my machine and simply copy pasted the command in your question (with my credentials). Can you try uploading it in a different couchdb like say [iris couch](http://www.iriscouch.com/) or cloudant and see if you get the same error.

Comment: OK, for some reason cutting and pasting into a new file solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your json is not valid. This doesn't work for me:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anatighe/sacred-harp/master/songs_raw2.json | python -m json.tool | view -
```

Might have to do with special characters / encoding?

Comment: Do you see any special characters in the data that might be an issue? I've run it through the JSON validator and it said it was valid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of the single quote characters are messing it up. In every place there should be a ', there appears to be a � for me. I'm on a mac, I don't know if that matters.

When I replaced the weird characters with regular single quotes the curl request worked fine.